# How to create fully customizable sections with Binding text?

Tags: forms, swiftui, binding

First of all, sorry for the title which is not precise at all, but I didn't know how else I could title this question. So:

**1. What I want to achieve:**

I want to create an interface where the user can add sections to input different fields, which are fully customizable by the user himself.

**2. What I have done so far**

I was able to create the interface, I can add new sections easily (structured with a "Section Name" on top and a TextField below) and they are customizable, but only in the TextField. They are also deletable, even though I had to do a complicated workaround since the Binding text of the TextField caused the app to crash because the index at which I was trying to remove the item resulted as "out of range". It's not the perfect workaround, but it works, and for now this is the most important thing. When I'll save these sections, I'll save them as an array of Dictionaries where every Dictionary has the section name and its value. However, there's still a few things I wasn't able to do:

**3. What I haven't done yet**

There are still 3 things that I couldn't do yet.

First of all, I'd like for the name of the section to be editable.

Secondly, I'd like to have the sections that the user adds displayed inside a Form and divided by Sections. As header, I'd like to have each different section name, and grouped inside all the related sections that share the same name.

Last but not least, I'd like to allow the user to add multiple TextFields to the same section. I have no idea how to handle this or even if it's possible.

**4. Code:**

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    
@State var editSections = false
@State var arraySections : [SectionModel] = [SectionModel(name: "Prova", value: ""), SectionModel(name: "Prova 2", value: ""), SectionModel(name: "Prova", value: "")]
@State var showProgressView = false
@State var arraySectionsForDeleting = [SectionModel]()
@State var openSheetAdditionalSections = false


var body: some View {
    Form {
        if showProgressView == false {
            if editSections == false {
                ForEach(arraySections, id: \.id) { sect in
                    Section(header: Text(sect.name)) {
                        ForEach(arraySections, id: \.id) { sez in
                            if sez.name == sect.name {
                                SectionView(section: sez)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                forEachViewSectionsForDeleting
            }
            if arraySections.count > 0 {
                buttoneditSections
            }
            
        } else {
            loadingView
        }
        
        Section {
            addSections
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $openSheetAdditionalSections, content: {
        AdditionalSectionsSheet(closeSheet: $openSheetAdditionalSections, contView: self)
    })
}






var forEachViewSectionsForDeleting : some View {
    Section {
        ForEach(arraySections, id: \.id) { sez in
            HStack {
                Text("\(sez.name) - \(sez.value)")
                    
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    showProgressView = true
                    let idx = arraySections.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == sez.id })
                    arraySectionsForDeleting.remove(at: idx!)
                    arraySections = []
                    arraySections = arraySectionsForDeleting
                    showProgressView = false
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                }).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            }
        }
    }
}
var buttoneditSections : some View {
    Button(action: {
        editSections.toggle()
    }, label: {
        Text(editSections == true ? "Done" : "Edit Sections")
            
            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
    })
}
var forEachviewSezioniNonModifica : some View {
    Section {
        ForEach(arraySections, id: \.id) { sez in
            Text(sez.name)
                
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            Text(sez.value)
                
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
    }
}
var addSections : some View {
    Button(action: {
        openSheetAdditionalSections = true
    }, label: {
        HStack {
            Text("Add sections")
                
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        }
    })
}
var loadingView : some View {
    Section {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            ProgressView()
                .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .black))
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
        }
    }
```

AddSectionSheet and SectionView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AdditionalSectionsSheet: View {
    
    @Binding var closeSheet : Bool
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    var contView : ContentView
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @GestureState private var dragOffset = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                buttonPhone
                buttonUrl
                buttonEmail
                buttonAddress
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Add section"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action : {
                closeSheet = false
            }){
                Text("Close")
                    
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            })
        }
    }
    
    var buttonPhone : some View {
        Button(action: {
            contView.editSections = false
            
            contView.arraySections.append(SectionModel(name: "Phone", value: ""))
            
            contView.showProgressView = true
            closeSheet = false
        }, label: {
            HStack {
                Text("Phone")
                    
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                Spacer()
            }
        })
    }
    var buttonUrl : some View {
        Button(action: {
            contView.editSections = false
            
            contView.arraySections.append(SectionModel(name: "URL", value: ""))
            
            closeSheet = false
        }, label: {
            HStack {
                Text("URL")
                    
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                Spacer()
            }
        })
    }
    var buttonAddress : some View {
        Button(action: {
            contView.editSections = false
            
            contView.arraySections.append(SectionModel(name: "Address", value: ""))
            
            contView.showProgressView = true
            closeSheet = false
        }, label: {
            HStack {
                Text("Address")
                    
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                Spacer()
            }
        })
    }
    var buttonEmail : some View {
        Button(action: {
            contView.editSections = false
            
            contView.arraySections.append(SectionModel(name: "Email", value: ""))
            
            contView.showProgressView = true
            closeSheet = false
        }, label: {
            HStack {
                Text("Email")
                    
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                Spacer()
            }
        })
    }
}

struct SectionView : View {
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    @ObservedObject var section : SectionModel
    
    var body : some View {
        Section {
            Text(section.name)
                
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            
            TextField(section.name, text: self.$section.value)
                
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
    }
}
```

SectionModel:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class SectionModel : Codable, Identifiable, Equatable, ObservableObject, Comparable {

    var id = UUID()
    var name : String
    var value : String
   
    init(name: String, value: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.value = value
}
    
    static func == (lhs: SectionModel, rhs: SectionModel) -> Bool {
        true
    }
    
    static func < (lhs: SectionModel, rhs: SectionModel) -> Bool {
        true
    }
}
```

I hope I wrote things clear enough to be understood, thanks to everyone who will help!

Comment: You should break up your code and what you want to do into smaller pieces and [only ask one question at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What part of your code for a specific task isn't working? You haven't even really asked a question here  all here you have listed your wishlist.

Comment: Sorry, the thing I have for now are working. But it's not as I would like it to be.The things I am missing are the three listed at point "3. What I haven't done yet"

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. If you are missing something you should try to implement it and if something specific doesn't work you can ask for help troubleshooting. One question at a time.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your feedback. I will try to implement the things I wrote about and I'll come back with a more structured question